# access values from enumerations scala object doesn't work

Tags: scala, enumeration

Hello I have the following enumeration and I want to get the values out of the enumeration defined : 
So here my enumeration object

```
object ConfType extends Enumeration {
  type ConfType = Value
  val Dfered = Value("Dfered")
  val Dedeo = Value("Dedeo")
 }
```

I want to define a new variable which has the value  equal to the String 
"Dfered" 
I tried this : 
`val confName: ConfType.Value ="Dfered"`. But I am getting an error. Do you have any idea how to resolce this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the string, try this:

```
val confName  = ConfType.Dfered.toString
```

Answer (score -1):

`val confName: ConfType.Value = ConfType.Dfered`

Comment: isn't this a ConfType.Value, or Enumeration.Value type rather than a String?

Comment: Sorry. I figured you wanted that since you explicitly put the type of your val to `: ConfType.Value`